# How to inflate a view in a fragment?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-fragments

I'm trying to assign content to a spinner in a fragment when the activity starts. I figured out that first I need to inflate the fragment, inflate the layout, and then inflate the view in order to assign it this piece of code:

```
 spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```

I've looked at other post on a question similar to this, and I'm not getting any luck. Ultimately, I'm not trying to fix my code, but rather find a piece of code that will allow me to to do spinner.setAdapter(adapter); without getting a NullPointerException. This action needs to happen when the activity starts, so basically it needs to involve the onCreate() method. Doing:

```
 Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
            R.array.priority_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```

putting this code inside the onCreate() will give me a NullPointerException because the spinner is inside the fragment and not the activity.

Here's the current code I am trying that doesn't work, but again, I'm looking for a solution to the problem not my code:

```
 public class ActivityInfo extends ActionBarActivity {

Spinner b;
Myfragment fragment;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_activity_info);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String name = intent.getStringExtra("Name");

    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    fragment = new Myfragment();
    fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.RelLayout, fragment);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();

    b = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    fragment.addSpinner();





}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_info, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

/**
 * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
 */

public static class Myfragment extends Fragment {

    RelativeLayout relativeLayout; 
     View rootView;
     @Override
        public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
           relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.RelLayout);
        }
     @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                     Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_activity_info, container, false);

         return rootView;
         }
     public void addSpinner()
      {

         Spinner spin = new Spinner(getActivity()); // needs activity context
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getActivity(),
                R.array.priority_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spin.setAdapter(adapter);
         relativeLayout.addView(spin);
      }
}
```

}

Comment: Do you want to inflate spinner with id spinner1?

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to inflate spinner1, that way spinner isn't null.

Comment: why not to inflate it in onCreateView?

Comment: that's what I tried in the code I posted, but it didn't work. But I now have my answer thanks to the response below. Thank you for responding though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try doing this:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_activity_info, null);
    Spinner spinner = (Spinner) rootView.findViewById(R.id.spinner1);

    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getActivity(),
        R.array.priority_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);

    return rl;
}
```

Comment: Wow, to be honest, I can't believe it was really that simple. I worked and researched for hours on how to do something like this, getting complex answers that didn't work. Thank you so much, this works exactly the way it should.

Comment: No problem, you are welcome. I hope you will sign my answer as correct one. Thanks